# Do I need to close a thread handle after the process has terminated?

Tags: windows, winapi

After creating process and immediately terminate it, is it necessary to `CloseHandle` the thread handle returned in the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` struct?

```
  STARTUPINFO si;
  GetStartupInfo(&si);
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
  CreateProcess(0, cmdLine, 0, 0, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0, 0, &si, &pi);

  TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);

  CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(pi.hThread);  // Is this necessary?
```

Comment: yes, of course you must close handle. necessary

Comment: Just like the process, the OS keeps data for the terminated thread.  You can legitimately call GetExitCodeProcess() and GetExitCodeThread() using these handles for example.  Or pass them to WaitForSingleObject().  How they ended makes no difference.  Cleaning up that data requires CloseHandle().

Comment: The answer is stated explicitly in the documentation. Your problem doesn't check for errors in any of its API calls, and so potentially could be passing uninitialized values to `CloseHandle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

handle (index in process handle table) this is indirect pointer to object (in your concrete case `ETHREAD`). if not close handle - object ( `ETHREAD` ) will be not free (until your process terminated, and all handles will be closed). are run process, thread or not - not play any role here. object will be not destroyed, until exist references (handles) for it

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the [docs for `CreateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa):

> Handles in PROCESS_INFORMATION must be closed with CloseHandle when they are no longer needed.

And in the [docs for `PROCESS_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-_process_information):

> Contains information about a newly created process and its primary thread. It is used with the CreateProcess, CreateProcessAsUser, CreateProcessWithLogonW, or CreateProcessWithTokenW function.
>
> [...]
>
> If the function succeeds, be sure to call the CloseHandle function to close the hProcess and hThread handles when you are finished with them.